# Find numbers that don't divide by 3 or 7

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I need help with a program. 
I need to write a program that prints on the console numbers from 1 to N that can't divide in the same time by 3 or 7. I need to parse N so the user inputs a value for it. Here is my code for now, can you tell me what is wrong?

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (n = 1; n <= 99999; n++) {
                //n % (3 * 7) == 0
```

I thought out how I will check it but I can't think out how to make the other part. I think there is something wrong with my loop too. Can you give me some hints where I am mistaken and what I can do? Thank you!

Comment: Read you code loud and you will see what is wrong with your Loop.

Comment: @Grumbler85, a very interesting exercise. I like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Modulus `%`

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int n;
if (int.TryParse(input, out n))
{
     for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
     {
          if(i % 3 != 0 ||  i% 7!= 0) Console.WriteLine(i);
     }
}
```

Your loop is wrong because your condition is wrong.It should be `i < n`, you are getting an input but then you overwriting it's value by `n = 1;`

Comment: `i %3 != 0 || i%7!= 0` maybe?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting N from the user then immediately overwriting it. Use a different variable for your loop:

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   // do stuff
```

Comment: Right, what a stupid mistake I made! I'll think more and post if I still need help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 21 != 0) { Console.Write(i + " "); }
    }
```

Example: http://ideone.com/ThASen